# 正規表現内の変数

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

正規表現内で変数が使えません。
特定の月の日付を集計したいのですが以下ですとうまくいきませんでした。

```
month=input()
re.findall(r'month/([0-9]{1,2})',data)
```

どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

正規表現で`month`が文字列になっていることがうまくいかない原因と予想されます。
下記のコードのように`format`関数などで月を書き換えてみてください。

```
import re
month = input()  // "01"を入力

data = """01/30
01/AA
02/20""" 

print(r'month/([0-9]{1,2})') # month/({0-9]{1,2}) が出力される
pattern = '{}/([0-9]{{1,2}})'.format(month)  # r''でない場合は、{{と}}が{と}に変換される
re.findall(pattern, data) # ['30']
```

それでもうまく行かない場合はエラーメッセージなどを追記してください。